# Item do map() passando por várias requisições

Tags: javascript, react, map

O código abaixo funcionou da forma que eu queria mas no último teste algo deu errado. Eu faço um `map` onde o item passava por várias requisições e no final eu definia meu objeto e daí um novo item varria as funções.
Agora, por alguma razão para cada função roda um `map`, atualizando sempre meu state a cada item.

```
getData() {
    array((item, index) => {
        if (item.x.length <= 11 && ((item.y == 8) || (item.y == 9))) {
            Requisição1(x, y).then((res) => {
                let data = (res.data ? res.data : []);
                this.setState({ state1: data }, () => {

                    Requisição2(x, y).then((res) => {
                        let data = (res.data ? res.data : []);
                        this.setState({ state2: data }, () => {


                            Requisição3(x, y).then((res) => {
                                let data = (res.data ? res.data : []);
                                this.setState({ state3: data }

                             let vendedor = {
                                                    dadosPessoa: this.state.sate1,
                                                    dadosTelefone: this.state.state2,
                                                    dadosEmail: this.state.state3,
                                                       }
                                                this.state.x.push(vendedor);
                                                this.setState({ sellerx: this.state.x });

                                            })

                                        })
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    }
                    )
                })
            }
            )
```

Comment: Compartilhe a mensagem de erro que você recebeu. Edite a pergunta e acrescente nela.

Comment: Não recebo erro, só não percorrer todas funções por item... É como se cada função chamasse um map.

Comment: Em `vendedor` estás a usar o state que mudaste nas requesições anteriores? Essas requesições têm de ser sequnênciais? Não podem ser em paralelo?